# if a variable calls a function are the results stored in the variable

Tags: python-2.7, variables

```
def use_api_get_data():
    url = ..
    r = request.get(url, headers)
    return json.loads(r.text)


def main()
    pages = use_api_get_data()

    for i in pages..
        for x in pages [i]
```

Question:

1. are the results of use_api_get_data() stored in the variable of pages or merely a call to the api?
2. the 2 loops using i in pages and x in pages... every time pages is called is it trying going back to requesting the information through the api or are the results stored.

My problem is my script requires several loops. Every time it loops is it asking the api for information again or is it just reading the information downloaded and saved in the variable of "pages" ?

TLDR trying to reduce calls to api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, from the way you call `use_api_get_data()`, it will call the api and return the response, which then saved in `pages` variable.

Second, your loop is only accessing the `pages` variables without calling the api repeatedly since `use_api_geet_data()` is not called in the loop, only the `pages` variable, which is already populated with the api response.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for thanks. I wasn't sure if pages was just acting as a pointer to a function.